# Unable to connect to VPS with SSH, failed authentication

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, putty, vps

I'm new to this whole VPS thing, and I'm having some problems with SSH. Basically, the password seems to be wrong, but I copied and pasted it from an email I got from the host, so it must be correct. I've also tried Putty, but I changed to Bitvise for the ability to paste the password.

Here is a screenshot of the login process:

[image]

Am I missing something here? I already reinstalled the OS from the control panel. It's currently running CentOS 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to type in your `username` in the field above `password`. It's currently empty in the screenshot.

I'm not familiar with Bitvise SSH Client, but I believe the dialog you have open on top which shows your Username entered is for Kerberos and other types of auth, not for simple SSH protocol.

Comment: I've tried that, still doesn't work. Do you mean the selection I have on "Method:" on the popup? That just comes up as default after a failed authentication, it won't help if I change it to "password" and try again.